# How can I set the default file format in the Delphi IDE to UTF8?

Tags: delphi, utf-8, delphi-2009, file-encodings

Delphi 2009 sets the default file format for new source code files to ANSI, this makes the source code platform-dependent.

Even for a new XSD file created in the IDE, which by default starts with this line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Delphi sets the file format to ANSI (this looks like a bug, for new XML and XSLT documents UTF8 is selected by default).

Is there a hidden option to set the default file format for source code files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no IDE-wide setting for specifying the default file format.

Comment: However the IDE does prompt you, when you enter a unicode character into the editor buffer, and then click Save.

Comment: Rob kennedy suggested that you can in fact, add a new Unit that is saved in UTF8 format to the Object Repository, and then use that from the File -> New menu. I found that it has to contain a high unicode character codepoint in order to keep the UTF8 encoding in new units though.

Comment: There's a setting  as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47813818/243614) answer.

Comment: With 10.4 there is now an option in the IDE.

Answer (score 12):

In fact [this blog post from 2004](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/more-ide-secrets--utf8-and-the-editor-284) mentions a hidden IDE option.
It states that you can set a default file filter in the registry to make UTF-8 the default encoding in Delphi 8. This still works under Tokyo! Clearly, you have to adapt the path of the registry key to recent versions like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\19.0\Editor]
"DefaultFileFilter"="Borland.FileFilter.UTF8ToUTF8"
```

After setting this value Delphi will encode new units in UTF-8 with BOM.

Answer (score 7):

Right-click on your source code in the Delphi 2009 IDE, and select File Format. Then choose UTF-8. Hope that helps.

Comment: I think the question was about doing that by default, so a new file starts off being set to UTF8.

Comment: This does not change the default file format for new files to UTF8, it has an effect only for the current file.

Comment: Not the original question but did help me :-)

Answer (score 7):

Although the [answer from MBulli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47813818/1960514) should be still relevant, since version 10.4 of Delphi (as far as I remember) it is possible to change the default encoding within the IDE.

Go to *Tools* > *Options* and choose *User interface* > *Editor* from the navigation area.

You will find the *Default file encoding* setting down below.

[image: Options window]

Comment: You're right it's just from 10.4 version, I checked in 10.3.2 and the option doesn't exist.

Comment: @Darkendorf: It is still okay though I think, since you can set the option manually in the Windows Registry...

Answer (score 4):

If you install [UTF8ize Plugin](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tales/20150618/1434639803) ([english translation of his page](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fd.hatena.ne.jp%2Ftales%2F20150618%2F1434639803) &  [latest version](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fd.hatena.ne.jp%2Ftales%2F20150904%2F1441377975&sandbox=1)) to your IDE, when you edit any file within the IDE, the plugin set the file's codepage to UTF8 automatically.

(FYI: The author creates many useful plugins. I posted some of his plugins with image here, but my post was deleted by the modelator. I just wanted to know his useful plugins, but yes, it's off topic here. sorry.)